# Update Qt GUI in Loop ( show Bitmap image as movie )

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, user-interface

i receive   screenshot   as  bitmap from socket  and  when i show  only one  of them it work 
but when i put  in loop ( show  all receive   image to make  movie) i get hang

```
void ShowImageBuffer(char* buf,int sizeofimagebuffer )
{
    QByteArray byte=QByteArray::fromRawData(buf, sizeofimagebuffer );
    QPixmap  image;
    if(image.loadFromData(byte,"BMP"))
    {
        ui->label->setPixmap(image);
        ui->label->update();
    }
}



  while(1)
 {
        ShowImageBuffer(buf, sizeofimagebuffer)
 }
```

i must use  separate thread?( but  i think  we will not use  any thread to change GUI?)

what is best to make  it real time?

Comment: You probably do not want a tight loop for this. You will see a significant performance increase if you maintain an array of `QPixmap` rather than allocating and converting raw image data to bitmap on every frame. Likewise after determining an acceptable frame rate use a timer and pre-loader to fetch the next frame while displaying the current one.

Comment: @AJG85 can you tell more  about "array of QPixmap rather than allocating and converting raw image data to bitmap on every frame."  can show source code?

Comment: `QVector<QPixmap>` might work. I have no intention of writing an application to play or buffer bitmaps as movie frames. Honestly if I were in your shoes I'd probably just use the Qt Phonon module which supports all sorts of media playback.

Comment: @AJG85 you say in paralel i store Qpixmap and  in timer  i only show it?( yes great ida) and   Qt Phonon( it will increase performance ?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem I suppose is that you're not returning to the event loop this way. The [update()](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/4.8/qwidget.html#update) method you're using doesn't repaint the QWidget immediately. It schedules a request to update the area, which is unified with other pending requests if any is available. This request is processed when the execution returns to the event loop. It is clearly stated in the documentation.

You might want to use a QTimer and invoke the ShowImageBuffer method at a specific frame rate. When the ShowImageBuffer is finished, execution returns to the event loop thus giving the time to process the update() request. Also consider the improvement suggested by AJG85.

Otherwise you can have a look at the [repaint()](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/4.8/qwidget.html#repaint) method which immediately invokes the paintEvent() method, but still I suppose you should set a specific frame rate to get a good result. I would go with the QTimer way.